# How to pass JWT token from Headers Set-Cookie to Authorization Headers in Strapi

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, strapi, headless-cms

[details="System Information"]

- **Strapi Version**:  4.1**
- **Operating System**:  Windows 11
- **Database**: Postgress
- **Node Version**:
- **NPM Version**:
- **Yarn Version**:
  [/details]

I wanted roles of users so I modified the response by adding extensions/strapi-server.js

```
// path: src/extensions/users-permissions/strapi-server.js
module.exports = (plugin) => {
  const sanitizeOutput = (user) => {
    const {
      password,
      resetPasswordToken,
      confirmationToken,
      ...sanitizedUser
    } = user; // be careful, you need to omit other private attributes yourself
    return sanitizedUser;
  };

  plugin.controllers.user.me = async (ctx) => {
    if (!ctx.state.user) {
      return ctx.unauthorized();
    }
    const user = await strapi.entityService.findOne(
      "plugin::users-permissions.user",
      ctx.state.user.id,
      {
        populate: {
          role: {
            fields: ["type"],
          },
        },
      }
    );
    ctx.body = sanitizeOutput(user);
  };
  return plugin;
};
```

So it looks like this, now to add cookie from Server Side i.e. HTTP Only, I added my custom endpoint (" /auth/login") in
`src/api/custom`

```
const axios = require("axios");
module.exports = {
  async index(ctx) {
    const { body } = ctx.request;
    const absoluteURL = `http://${hostname}:${strapi.config.server.port}`;
    const sanitizeOutput = (user) => {
      const {
        password,
        resetPasswordToken,
        confirmationToken,
        ...sanitizedUser
      } = user;
      return sanitizedUser;
    };
    try {
      console.log("Tryin to login");
      let { data } = await axios.post(`${absoluteURL}/api/auth/local`, body);
      const populatedUser = await strapi.entityService.findOne(
        "plugin::users-permissions.user",
        data.user.id,
        {
          populate: {
            role: {
              fields: ["type"],
            },
          },
        }
      );
      data.user = sanitizeOutput(populatedUser);
      if (data && data.jwt) {
        ctx.cookies.set("jwt", data.jwt, {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: false,
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14, // 14 Day Age
          domain: "localhost",
        });
      }
      // Respond with the jwt + user data, but now this response also sets the JWT as a secure cookie
      return ctx.send(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("An error occurred:", error.response);
      return ctx.badRequest(null, error);
    }
  }
};
```

Now from my Frontend, I am calling /auth/login, which returns just and user and sets the cookie from server i.e. HTTP Only, Now When I am calling /users/me, it says UnAuthorized

I know what could be the problem is,
all protected endpoints in strapi take Authorization: Bearer token Headers but in this, it's automatically passed with Set-Cookie, thus for strapi endpoints no headers are passed.

the solution could be, somethings from which before the request is hit to the /users/me, Cookie from Headers are taken then placed in Authorization and then hit the API, all this in the backend

Something like this mentioned here,
[How to put JWT's in server-side cookies using the Strapi user-permissions plugin](https://talke.dev/strapi-user-permissions-jwt-cookies)
on the Modify Auth Handler

### I tried but it seems this permissions.js and all mentioned in the article is of v3.** as reference links mentioned there are of v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing some research I found what to do for this.
So basically, I setup-ed a middleware whose work was to get the jwt token from header cookies and set `Authorization: Bearer token`

## Answer

### Create custom middleware

./src/middlewares/TokenPlacer.js
(Filename can be of your choice)

```
module.exports = () => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    const cookies = ctx.request.header.cookie || false;
    if (cookies) {
      let token = cookies
        .split(";")
        .find((c) => c.trim().startsWith("jwt="))
        .split("=")[1];
      if (token) {
        ctx.request.header.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }
    }
    await next();
  };
};
```

Here I have saved my JWT token as `jwt` in the cookie so change it accordingly!

### Load the custom middleware

Then locate the middleware file in `./config/middleware.js`
If you haven't used any middleware or customized anything then it should look like this

```
module.exports = [
  "strapi::errors",
  "strapi::security",
  "strapi::cors",
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::session",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];
```

Now here we need to tell the Strapi to load our custom middleware
So just add `"global::__YOUR__MIDDLEWARE_FILENAME__",` at the end, so for me it `"global::TokenPlacer",` , so it would look like this now

```
module.exports = [
  "strapi::errors",
  "strapi::security",
  "strapi::cors",
  "strapi::poweredBy",
  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::session",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
  "global::TokenPlacer",
];
```

[Learn more about Strapi Middleware and customize accordingly - Official Strapi Docs v4](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/middlewares.html)